# Extracting column name from CSV filename during import

Tags: r

I have 24 CSV files to import, each with three columns of data: type (CHR), buffer (INT), mean (NUM).  I import these using:

```
data <- list.files(path = "...", pattern = "*.csv", full.names = TRUE) %>% 
lapply(read_csv) %>%                                            
bind_rows
```

This creates a 'long' data table containing three columns of data.

To enable monthly analysis I need to extract a date from the filename of each imported CSV to create a 'wide' table (with a column for each **date**), or a 'long' table with **date** as another column).

Although I've found quite a few suggested ways of doing this I can't get anything to work (I'm relatively new to R) and have become a b it confused by unfamiliar syntax.

The CSV filename is in the format ABC_YYYY-MM-DD.CSV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would create a long table with `date` as 4th column -

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- list.files(path = "...", pattern = "*.csv", full.names = TRUE) %>%
          sapply(read_csv, simplify = FALSE) %>%
          imap_dfr(~.x %>% 
          mutate(date = sub('.*(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}).*', '\\1', basename(.y))))
```

`sapply` with `simplify = FALSE` would create a list with names of the list as file name. Using `imap_dfr` we combine all the data in one dataframe and create a new column `date` extract the date from the list name.

Comment: Thanks - I will try that now!  The syntax - is imap_dfr part of base R or tidyverse?

Comment: It works, but I don't understand how.  I'll read up on sapply(), imap_dfr() and sub().  Thanks for your help.  :)

Comment: Usually the help page has that information. From `?imap_dfr` you'll notice that it is from `purrr` library which is part of `tidyverse`. To better understand I would suggest you to run the code line by line so that you know what happens in each line.

Comment: Thanks, Ronak.  I'll do that.